# How much do I cut and how much do I leave

Tags: discussion, answers, editing

https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/131096/4188 this is a highly upvoted answer but it is now outdated because DT 564 / 565 now exists between Lagos and Luanda M/W/F. This makes most / all of the answer outdated. *However* some of it (Moscow-Havanna,Istanbul-Panama City) is a good collection of non-EU transatlantic flights. So how much should I cut and how much should I add? Should I just add the new simplified answer after the Turkey section, add a note after "there are other possibilities but now these are less good" and leave the rest?

Answer (score 7):

You should update the answer with the most recent information, so that it becomes accurate, factual, and complete. Hence, you should cut out the outdated parts, insert the updated ones, and re-write all the statements which are not true as of today.

Comment: OK, I edited it down to what I would write now and didn't leave anything historical.